# The meaning of BARREL

Tags: meaning

In the sentence below I'd like to ask the meaning of BARREL in this context.

> I'm not interested in dressing in the latest mode; a ***barrel*** and a pair
>   of flipflops are fashionable enough for me.

It seems that a ***barrel*** refers to a kind of dress. 
But dictionary don't give me any meaning with regard to this meaning.

Comment: Sometimes *barrel* means [barrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankruptcy_barrel).

Comment: Where is this excerpt from?

Comment: Standing with a barrel around you is a common trope in old comics for the minimal thing to cover oneself as clothes. So terribly unfashionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, the meaning is that the person doesn't care about clothes too much. They'd be happy wearing a hollow cylindrical drum around themselves with flip flops.

To the author's mind, a barrel covers your body just as well as clothes do and hence equally good.

[image]